# PowerShell PnP for all sub-sites with title contains

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am trying to following script to look in our site collection for any sites with title containing "Friday".

I know there should be at least 4 sites that have "Friday" in the site title, but this brings back nothing:

```
    $varURL = Read-Host -Prompt 'Provide URL to site'
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $varURL -UseWebLogin

Function Get-Subsites() {  
    $subwebs= Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse | where {$_.Title -contains "FRIDAY" }

     foreach ($Subweb in $subwebs)  
    {  
       Write-Host $Subweb.Title
    }  
}   
Get-SubSites
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `-like` operator, not `-contains` :

```
$subwebs= Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse | where {$_.Title -like "*friday*" }
```

**Contains** is used to check if a specific member is part of an array, thus it will only return exact matches to the string.

For example:

```
❯ $test = @("Friday", "Fridays are the best.", "Yay friday!", "Saturdays are great also.")                                                                                             

❯ $test | where {$_ -contains "friday"}
Friday

❯ $test | where {$_ -like "*friday*" }
Friday
Fridays are the best.
Yay friday!
```

Comment: thank you...changing to -like worked great!

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell, never use `-contains`. Instead, use `-match`. If you make this change your script will work perfectly fine:

```
$varURL = Read-Host -Prompt 'Provide URL to site'
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $varURL -UseWebLogin

Function Get-Subsites() {  
    $subwebs= Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse | where {$_.Title -match "FRIDAY" }

     foreach ($Subweb in $subwebs)  
    {  
       Write-Host $Subweb.Title
    }  
}   
Get-SubSites
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran the above the script and it returns the data as expected. couple of things to check.

- Make sure you are entering the correct url of the Site collection (sometime we enter the tenant root with thought it may go all other site collection, which is not true)
- try to run this command this way and see if you get anything and if you see Friday in title.

  Connect-PnPOnline -Url "Url of site" -UseWebLogin
  Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse

*Pnp only connect to one site collection at a given time.